# Compare 2 columns in FeathersJs-Client query

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs

I'm using Feathersjs along with Sequelize. I want to query data where updatedAt > createdAt + 1 day.

```
this.$feathers.service("data").find({
     query: {
         updatedAt:{
             $gt: ¿¿createdAt?? + 24*60*60*1000
         }
     }
});
```

of course I get ReferenceError at createdAt. How can I reference another column from the client? I don't want to modify the backend for this query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare 2 columns , `sequelize.col` is what you need :

```
query: { updatedAt: { $gt: sequelize.col('createdAt') } }
```

Comment: how can I get the reference to `sequelize` from `feathersjs-client` ? I want to achieve this in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way is to create a before hook and set a user-defined variable:

```
function(context) {
  const { query } = context.params;
  if(query.timeSinceCreated) {
    query.updatedAt = {
      $gt: sequelize.col('createdAt') // + 1 day
    }
    // delete the special variable so it's not used in the query
    delete query.timeSinceCreated;
  }
}
```

so then you can query from the client this way:

```
this.$feathers.service("data").find({
   query: {
       timeSinceCreated: 24*60*60*1000
   }
});
```